# OAuth POST succeeds, GET fails

Tags: actionscript-3, oauth, get, access-token, stackmob

I create a brand new schema called 'blogpost' with the service http://www.Stackmob.com. Its read/write access is granted to authenticated users.

After authenticating as a user to my schema, my POST queries succeeds, but GET fails with 
{"error":"Invalid OAuth credentials or signature: Key not provided"}

I don't understand this because the authentication header in my POST/GET requests are created from the exact same function, which takes input mac_key and access_token values granted to a user from the server.

Why would this be? Details of the code post is also at:
http://stackmob.zendesk.com/entries/27724236-Invalid-OAuth-credentials-or-signature-Key-not-provided

I hope this is not a Flash11 restriction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter API Issue: OAuth Request Token using GET works, POST fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795830/twitter-api-issue-oauth-request-token-using-get-works-post-fails)